# How to enable ONLY TLS 1.2 in Java, blocking SSL TLS1.0 and TLS 1.1

Tags: tls, java, tls-downgrade

I'm creating my SSL context like this:

```
SSLContext ret = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```

When I went in firefox and forced it to disable TLS1.2, I noticed the page still loaded using TLS1.1

I would like to make sure the server ONLY allows TLS1.2 -- does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: The question is already answered on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466407/how-to-force-java-server-to-accept-only-tls-1-2-and-reject-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-c

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledProtocols-java.lang.String:A-). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#jssenames) are the valid names for protocols.